# Prevent Windows 10 from going to sleep on lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, lock-screen, energy

How can I prevent Windows 10 from going to sleep on the lock screen? I want the screen to stay on forever on the lock screen without moving the mouse.

This would be easy to achieve if I was signed in and viewing my desktop, but that's not what I'm looking for: [How to adjust power and sleep settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-adjust-power-and-sleep-settings-26f623b5-4fcc-4194-863d-b824e5ea7679). The computer still turns off the screen after a very short time on lock screen (probably a minute).

Comment: You should be able to set your monitor (not the computer) to stay on. That is, remove power saving setting from the monitor. Your computer does not have to sleep. My computer is running 24x7 and it is only the screen that comes into play.

Comment: My monitor doesn't go to sleep by itself. There are no power saving options in the settings of my monitor. My computer turns off the screen and goes to sleep, it's not the monitor. When the screen turns off, my monitor says there is no input signal which means that Windows doesn't give the monitor a picture to display. So it is Windows' fault. Windows controls when the screen turns off and I have to change the settings in Windows and not on my monitor. The question is where to find the right settings to make the screen stay alive forever on lock screen?

Comment: I will look around.  Like most I know, I like the monitor off when not using it.

Comment: Go to Power Settings in Windows, and set the Display Off time to Never.  Restart the computer and check the screen stays on. Now try locking the screen. I am not sure if this will work, but if it does not work, you are most likely out of luck on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display timeout on the lock screen is under `Console lock display off timeout` in Power Options advanced settings. The setting is hidden by default and can be enabled in the registry.

Open the Registry Editor by clicking start and type `regedit`.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7`. Double-click `Attributes` and change the value data from `1` to `2`.

[image: Registry Editor]

Click start and type `edit power plan`, open it then click `Change advanced power settings`.

Expand `Display` then you should be able to see the `Console lock display off time-out` setting.

[image: Power Options]

Change this to whatever suits you. 0 for never.